# GCP HTTP Load Balancer open many ports

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I found that many ports are opened in my HTTP Load Balancer IP address. But It should be only opened at 80, 443, and 8080.

I've read the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#open_ports), and they do explain some views why running a port scan is not useful.

But I would like to know the deep reason for understanding the fundamental architecture.

Comment: The only ports that should concern you are the ones that you open via frontend listeners. The other ports are under Google's control and management. Load Balancers are part of shared resources. The other resources do not affect you. Google does publish white papers on the architecture of load balancers, GFEs, and Envoy Proxies. Edit your question so that you are asking an on-topic question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, the white paper is this
[link](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/security_whitepapers_march2018.pdf) ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/static/docs/security/infrastructure/design/resources/google_infrastructure_whitepaper_fa.pdf There are many more white papers to research that Google has written.

Comment: This one is good: https://research.google/pubs/pub44824.pdf

Comment: @JohnHanley, Thank you for helping, I've appreciated it and going to work on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of global Load balancers:

- Global HTTP(S) Load balancer - L7
- Global TCP/SSL proxy Load Balancer - L4

Both load balancers use GFE Proxies to proxy client's traffic to the backend application. [GFE proxies are distributed around the world](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/about-capacity-optimization-with-global-lb#how_https_load_balancing_works) and are [shared for Google APIs traffic as well as GCLB traffic](https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/design#secure_internet_communication). So in the port scan, it would establish and respond to TCP connection. However, if the Load balancer's VIP:Port number does not match with the Destination IP:Port, the traffic will not be forwarded to their backend and the application does not face any security risk.